# SQL Server Compact Toolbox Not Connecting to Databases

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-toolbox

I am using SQL Server Compact Toolbox for runtime 3.5.

When I select 'Add SQL Server Compact 3.5 Connection' I get what you can see in the following image. The problem is that after clicking 'Test Connection' and 'OK' nothing happens. The list on the left does not have the database I am connecting to.

[image]

The database you can see there, `3.sdf` is an empty database I created using the 'Create' button. That is the only database I have been able to connect to.

I have tried running the compact toolbox application as administrator, but that didn't seem to help. Also tried playing with the file permissions in the database folder, that didn't seem to help either.

This is what I have installed on my machine,

[image]

Update:

Yes I am using the latest version 3.1.4.0.

So the exact steps are this,

1. Right click SQL Server Compact Data Connections
2. Click Add SQL Server Compact 3.5 Connection
3. Click browse and select the filename, for me it is C:\temp1\1.sdf
4. Edit the Max database size in MB field. Set it to 500
5. Hit Test Connection. Nothing happens which is the first sign of an issue
6. Hit OK. The dialog disappears and the new connection does not appear in the list

Comment: I have tried to repro, bu could not, with the latestversion (3.1.4.0) Could you describe the exact steps to reproduce? (I am the author of the tool)

Comment: Repo steps added. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: And the 1.sdf file is created before you launch the app?

Comment: Yes it is a file that was created a while ago. It has not been opened or modified recently, i.e. it is not open while sql compact toolbox is trying to open it.

Comment: Pls try the latest release...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 1.sdf is not a SQL Server Compact 3.5 file, and for some reason you get no error message (it has been fixed in version 3.5.1.0). You can use the "Detect SQL Server Compact file version" menu option to verify.

Comment: The menu option says it is a sql compact 3.5 file. '1.sdf is SQL Server Compact version 3.5' is what it is saying.

Comment: This issue is fixed in the latest Toolbox release

Comment: I have finally needed to use this tool again, and it appears to work. One problem I had though was the Max database size field does not work for me. When I open a large database the only way to specify the max database size is to manually add it to the connection string. Max Database Size = 1000. Setting that value in the field gives me the error 'The database file is larger than the configured etc'. But the field is definately set high enough.

Comment: I will look into it - you use the standalone version?

Comment: Yes I use the standalone version. By the way this tool is excellent for comparing database structures. Thanks. I am testing database structure upgrades.

Comment: Standalone version 3.7 fixes the "Max Database Size" issue

Comment: Thanks. I tested the Max Database Changes you made and it works fine.